# Tab Key is not capturing ng-click

Tags: html, angularjs

Am new to Angularjs,Am using a ng-click option,but when i press a tab key in the keyboard ,ng-click is not capturing.Tab key is capturing only Href,how to enable Tab key to capture ng-click.

```
<th><a href="#/providerSearch" class="nameCross"><img src="img/cross.png" ng-click="goBack()"></a>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</th>
                    <th>{{licNum}}</th>
                    <th>{{city}}</th>
                    <th>{{stCode}}</th>
                    <th>In Network</th>
                    <th>{{specialty}}</th>
                    <th>{{phone}}</th>
                    <th>{{tin}}</th>
                    <th class="smallWidth noteIcon" ng-click="fetchPrvdNts()" ><div ng-show="count>0" class="countBuble">{{count}}</div></th>
                    <th class="smallWidth moreDetails" ng-click="showMoreDtls()" ng-class="{open:!showDetailsBlock , close:showDetailsBlock}">More</th>
```

pressing on Tab key its focusing on first href line,but after pressing tab key there its not capturing the ng-click functionality for{{count}}.Can anyone help me with it

Answer (score 2):

Use [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.tabIndex) attribute to control what element gain focus on Tab key press. However if your goal is to allow use to navigate to clickable element with tab and then be able to trigger action with Enter or something like this, you will need to make controller listen keyboard event also, as well as click. You can do something like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" tabindex="1">Link</a>
<span ng-keypress="test($event)" ng-click="test()" tabindex="2">Test</span>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.test = function(e) {
    if ((e && e.keyCode === 13) || typeof e === 'undefined') {
        alert('test');
    }
};
```

<sub>Can it be done simpler?</sub>

#### Demo experiment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZUv2V1uy7ov6ix4JEQdp?p=preview

Comment: Thank you,we cannot give the tab index,as we donot know what all the functionalities we use in depth,suppose if we click on a link it will show a dropdown menu with certain buttons,if we give the tab index we cannot capture the buttons in dropdown menu if we click on that link,so we cannot hardcode the tab index,please help if there is another solution for this problem